# about ZeroMQ and using an alternative storage to store messages

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, zeromq

I learnt recently that a ZeroMQ socket connected to another socket (I am using PUSH/PULL) keeps on pushing data even if the socket pulling data goes offline or disconnect.

My understanding is that everything is accumulated in memory and as soon as the socket will be online again, it will continue pulling from the point it stopped.

Is there any way to setup ZeroMQ to use a file storage instead of memory for this behavior?  If so is it event driven telling when the socket realize about the disconnection of the re-connection of the Puller?

I like the concept but I am scared by the excessive usage of memory and I do nor want to use a watermark which might block the socket.

I am using ZeroMQ under C/C++ for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no such built-in function. If you want to store message into a file you're gonna have to implement it yourself.

From experience (I used ZMQ quite extensively) I would say that your solution is more complex and not necessary. 
If really you feel like RAM will be a problem, a much better solution would to create a SWAP file and to limit the RAM's usage of your process using [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) ([example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cgroups#Ad-hoc_groups)).
The consequence will be that your process will use whatever max RAM you allowed and then use SWAP RAM (which is basically a file) to store queued message.

Comment: Thanks 'Clank'. Yes it could be a way. What I see with this approach of having the swap space per-app is that the swap  will be used also by the whole application (every usage of the heap will go to swap) causing an overall slow down. I would have preferred a dedicated storage specifically dedicated to MESSAGE . In any case I didn't know about 'cgroups' before and it is definitely something I'll try to see what's it like.

Comment: While it's true that Swap file is slower, you really should test it to see if it has a mesurables impact. Slower doesn't mean it's not still fast enough :)

Comment: absolutely true!

Answer (score 1):

> ... keeps on pushing data even if the socket pulling data goes offline or disconnect.

### No, not necessarily

this behaviour is a result of a certain configuration, not a uniformly valid behaviour.

Read about all of
**`.setsockopt( zmq.IMMEDIATE, ... )`** and
**`.setsockopt( zmq.CONFLATE, ... )`** and
**`.setsockopt( zmq.SNDHWM, ... )`** and
**`.setsockopt( zmq.SNDBUF, ... )`**

> ... everything is accumulated ... and as soon as the socket will be online again, it will continue pulling

### No, not necessarily

this behaviour is a result of a certain configuration, not a uniformly valid behaviour.

Read about all of
**`.setsockopt( zmq.SNDHWM, ... )`** and
**`.setsockopt( zmq.SNDBUF, ... )`** and
**`.setsockopt( zmq.SNDTIMEO, ... )`** and
**`.setsockopt( zmq.BACKLOG, ... )`** and
**`.setsockopt( zmq.RECONNECT_IVL, ... )`** and
**`.setsockopt( zmq.RECONNECT_IVL_MAX, ... )`** and
O/S dependent tuning options

> ... setup ZeroMQ to use a file storage instead of memory for this behavior?

### No, not available

High-watermarking is a sort of a last resort to activate a "fuse"-breaker ( I do not like to say protection upon a feature, that does not protect something ).

Explicit extended multiparty signalling / handshaking is a better strategy to go, showering the **`Context()`**-instances with numerous payload data, which is intended for not-ready peers gets better controlled from app-side, not by allocating more and more resources somewhere down there under the hood, does it?

Comment: ...I got a long and painful road ahead of me...:|  thanks for your response. Got to read a lot this weekend before getting back to you about it.